# Android How to View image from sd card dynamically ? My code atached

Tags: java, android, dynamic, imageview, android-imageview

i am able to place image in image view. but when i do it dynamically i cant get image

Let check this code for one image view we can get image in it code is,

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;
private ImageView img1;
String imageOne = "";
```

Create image object and its onclick method,

```
img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
```

Method to get image from sd card,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img1.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
                imageOne = Base64.encodeToString(bb, Base64.DEFAULT);
                imageOne = addQuotes(imageOne);
            }
```

Get Uri method used above,

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

this code is working fine but when i try to convert it dynamically getting id error in onActiveResult method

my dynamic code is,

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MultiQuesRelaLayOut);

final ImageView[] im=new ImageView[10];
for(int img=0;img<2.length;img++)
    {
         im[img]=new ImageView(this);   
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    ((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.leftMargin=25;
            params.topMargin=(img+1)*(35+add);
            im[img].setId(img);
            im[img].layout(5,5,5,5);
            im[img].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            im[img].setBackgroundColor(color.background_dark);
            im[img].setPadding(5, 15, 5, 15);
            im[img].setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(im[img]);
            im[img].setOnClickListener(ImageOnClick(im[img]));
    }
```

Here is onclick method for dynamic image view,

```
View.OnClickListener ImageOnClick(final ImageView image) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Image pressed is: "+ image.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    image.getId());
        }
    };
}
```

Method to get image from sd card,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                data.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) data.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Geturi method is same for both.

In `onActivityResult` method i am unable to get **ID** for **imageview** that is causing issue how to resolve it hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int img=0;img<2.length;img++)    //  2.length? is this correct?
```

add

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

to your class
and instead of

```
// m[img].setOnClickListener(ImageOnClick(im[img]));
m[img].setOnClickListener(this);
```

add this method to your class

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //  v.getId()  there you have it
```